# Logstash multiline codec not working with my pattern

Tags: logstash, multiline, codec, logstash-grok

I had been using the multline codec of logstash for my java exceptions. However, recently I wanted to capture more things and hence used another pattern. This causes my logstash not to read file even though I am using sincedb_path attribute.

My configurations file -

```
input {
        file {
           type => "pa"
           path => "/home/jigar/POC/Docs/smalllogs/test"
           codec => multiline {
                pattern => "^%{DATESTAMP}"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
           }
           start_position => "beginning"
           sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}

filter {
         grok {
           match => [ "message", "%{DATESTAMP:actualTimeStamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:identifier}%{SYSLOG5424SD:Id}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:package}:%{INT:lineNum}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{DATA:mydata}\n(\t)?%{GREEDYDATA:stack}" ]
         }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
        cluster => "smartdebugger"
        protocol => "http"
        host => "localhost"
  }
  stdout { codec =>rubydebug }
}
```

Can somebody please help me why logstash is not able to read the file.

Comment: Do you get any output from the stdout output{} stanza?

Comment: I get the normal output without any errors

Comment: I solved this for now by implementing the multiline filter

Comment: will you please provide me the whole config file?